# global variable {{ siteUrl }} in multilingual sites

Tags: craft3, localization, variable, siteurl

In multilingual sites the global variable {{ siteUrl }} should not point to the URL with "/de/" if it is included in the templates head section for pointing to a global js-file or css-file (eg. href="{{ siteUrl }}css/normalize.css" results for the German language versions in https:///example.com/de/cc/normalize.css) which does not exist. Is there a specific global variable which points to the default url regardless of the localization)?

The site settings are as shown in below screenshoot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 3.6.0, `siteUrl` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/main/src/config/GeneralConfig.php#L1478-L1481), instead, in your instance, you could use `{{ alias('@web') }}`.